# add two cell in the same indexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to add two cell in the same index path, or something like that.

My object that represent each cell.

```
var object = [[category: "book", title: "blabla"],
              [category: "book", title: "blabla"],
              [category: "game", title: "blabla"], 
              [category: "game", title: "blabla1"],
              [category: "movie", title: "blabla"]]
```

So, i feed my collectionView by each element, but i need to add a title cell to have a result like

```
 __Title cell book
 ____cell book
 ____ceel book
 __Title cell game
 ____cell game
 ____cell game
__Title cell movie
____cell movie
____cell movie
```

So is it possible to tell "when the we are on the first element from category X add a  title cell ? Or i need to add an element title in my array ?

Comment: is this pure static content or is it dynamically generated (i.e. from database)?

Comment: I think you are looking for Sections, with potentially a section header.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `sections` for each category.

```
Section1: book
    Cell1: book1
    Cell2: book2
...
```

Also, take a look at `UICollectionView` [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview)